# Converting Traditional Logic to XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

Just trying to convert the below simple code into XSLT and I tried to use Regular expressions with XSLT 2.0 but some how it is not working. Could any one please advice? Thank you.

```
string[256] Fname;
integer ctr;
Fname="";
ctr=0;
while ctr <= len(#FirstName) do
begin
  if mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "A" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "B" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "C" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "D" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "E" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "F" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "G" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "H" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "I" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "J" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "K" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "L" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "M" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "N" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "O" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "P" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "Q" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "R" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "S" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "T" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "U" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "V" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "W" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "X" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "Y" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "Z" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "a" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "b" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "c" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "d" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "e" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "f" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "g" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "h" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "i" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "j" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "k" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "l" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "m" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "n" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "o" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "p" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "q" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "r" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "s" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "t" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "u" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "v" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "w" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "x" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "y" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "z" |
     mid(#FirstName,ctr,1) = "-" 
     then
   Fname = Fname + mid(#FirstName,ctr,1);
  ctr = ctr+1;
end

Fname = trimleft(Fname,"-");

if len(Fname) = 2 then
   Fname = Fname + "-";
if len(Fname) = 1 then
   Fname = Fname + "--";

if len(Fname) > 50 then
   Fname = left(Fname,50);

if len(Fname) = 0 then
   Fname = "UNKNOWN";

#FirstName = Fname;
```

Solution:
Same logic is applied on another filed called PostalCode and here is what I tried but some how regular expression not working. I am trying to fix it mean while posting here as well for experts solutions.

```
   <xsl:if test="contains(substring(string(/OrdersToFulfill/Order/OrderHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalCode),1,1),'[^a-zA-Z1-9. ]')">
                            <xsl:variable name="vPostalCode"
                                          select="concat(string(/OrdersToFulfill/Order/OrderHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalCode),substring(string(/OrdersToFulfill/Order/OrderHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalCode),1,1))"/>
                            <xsl:element name="PostalCode">
                                <xsl:if test="string-length($vPostalCode) &lt; 9 ">
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                            select="substring($vPostalCode,1, 5)"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="string-length(string(/OrdersToFulfill/Order/OrderHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalCode)) &gt; 10 ">
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                            select="substring($vPostalCode,1, 10)"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: The `contains` function is defined in XSLT/XPath 1.0 and does not offer any regular expression support. If you want to use regular expressions then in XPath/XSLT 2.0 there are the functions `matches`, `tokenize` and `replace` and the instruction `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: IMHO, it would be much better to describe the required logic **in words** and provide an example or two.

Comment: Generally, reverse-engineering procedural code is difficult; it's much better to start with a statement of requirements. The other problem is that although your code looks as if it's in a language I might have used in the past, I certainly can't remember what the mid() function does.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've worked out what your code does: it constructs a string containing all the letters, digits, and hyphens from an input string, and removes everything else. It then pads with hyphens to a minimum length of three, and truncates to a maximum length of 50. (Why couldn't you have told us that?)

Also, if you tried to write the code and it didn't work then you should show us the code so we can tell you where you went wrong.

The first part of the problem can be done using

```
replace($in, "[^A-Za-z0-9\-]", "")
```

Padding with hyphens to length 3 can be done with

```
if (string-length($s) lt 3) 
then substring(concat($s, "---"), 1, 3) 
else $s
```

Truncation to a maximum of 50 characters can be done with

```
substring($s, 1, 50)
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Kay. I just followed @ Martin Honnen instructions and yours and I was able to apply regex and solve my issue. Regarding problem description sorry about that as I was out of home after posting the question. WIll keep that in mind. Thanks a lot for suggestions. My problem solved.